# Haskell GPGME much slower at signing than GPG

Tags: haskell, profiling, gnupg, gpgme

My program uses GPG for signing files. I'm using [GPGME](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/h-gpgme) in Haskell and the issue is that it is about 16 times slower than using GPG from the command line. Here is an example:

Haskell code:

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Crypto.Gpgme as Gpg

main :: IO ()
main = do
    fileContents <- B.readFile "randomfile"
    eitherSigned <- sign fileContents
    case eitherSigned of
        Left err -> print err
        Right signed ->
            B.writeFile "signedfile" signed

sign :: B.ByteString -> IO (Either [Gpg.InvalidKey] B.ByteString)
sign bs =
    let
        sign' :: Gpg.Ctx -> IO (Either [Gpg.InvalidKey] Gpg.Plain)    
        sign' ctx = Gpg.sign ctx [] Gpg.Normal bs
    in
        Gpg.withCtx "/home/t/.gnupg" "C" Gpg.OpenPGP sign'
```

I generate a junk 10MB file with

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=randomfile bs=10000000 count=1
```

I sign it with GPG from the command line:

```
$ time gpg -s randomfile
```

and get

```
gpg -s randomfile  0.14s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.136 total
```

I sign it with my Haskell program with

```
$ time stack exec hasksign
```

and get

```
stack exec hasksign  0.27s user 0.07s system 14% cpu 2.239 total
```

I tried running the Haskell code again with profiling on and got this result:

```
       hasksign +RTS -p -RTS randomfile

    total time  =        2.21 secs   (2208 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 115,627,312 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE        MODULE                SRC                                           %time %alloc

newCtx             Crypto.Gpgme.Ctx      src/Crypto/Gpgme/Ctx.hs:(21,1)-(51,21)         77.0    0.0
signIntern         Crypto.Gpgme.Crypto   src/Crypto/Gpgme/Crypto.hs:(310,1)-(354,14)    20.4    8.6
collectResult.go.\ Crypto.Gpgme.Internal src/Crypto/Gpgme/Internal.hs:(29,21)-(34,46)    2.1   81.9
main               Main                  src/Main.hs:(7,1)-(13,43)                       0.1    8.7
```

I have looked in the [newCtx](https://github.com/rethab/h-gpgme/blob/master/src/Crypto/Gpgme/Ctx.hs) function where the time is spent but it is not clear to me what is costing so much.

Comment: 1.5s to initialize the library does seem a bit crazy. Perhaps it's time to add some cost centers inside the gpgme library so you can see what's taking so long in there.

Comment: What does "add some cost centers" mean please?

Comment: [GHC’s profiling system assigns costs to cost centres. A cost is simply the time or space (memory) required to evaluate an expression. Cost centres are program annotations around expressions; all costs incurred by the annotated expression are assigned to the enclosing cost centre.](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html)